# Aggregate function on one column, group by on another, leave a third unaffected

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I feel like this isn't too bad of a problem but I've been looking for a solution for the greater part of the day to no avail. Other solutions I've seen plenty of that don't seem to help me have been for getting columns that aren't unique values along with a group by and aggregate function.

**The problem**

I have a table of historical data as follows:

```
ID | source | value | date
---+--------+-------+-----------
1  | 12     | 10    | 2016-11-16
2  | 12     | 20    | 2015-11-16
3  | 12     | 30    | 2014-11-16
4  | 13     | 40    | 2016-11-16
5  | 13     | 50    | 2015-11-16
6  | 13     | 60    | 2014-11-16
```

I'm trying to get data before a certain date(within a loop to go different ranges), then getting the sum of the values grouped by source. So as an example "get all records before 30 days ago, and get the sum of the values of the unique sources, using the most recent dated entry for each".

So the first step was to remove entries with dates not in the range, an easy `where date < getdate()-30` for example to get:

```
ID | source | value | date
---+--------+-------+-----------
2  | 12     | 20    | 2015-11-16
3  | 12     | 30    | 2014-11-16
5  | 13     | 50    | 2015-11-16
6  | 13     | 60    | 2014-11-16
```

Now my issue is finding a way to `group by` source and take the `max` date, and then sum up the result across all sources. The idea hear is that we don't know when the last entry is, so before the specified date we get all records, then take the newest entry for each unique source, and sum those up to get the total value at that time.

So the next step would be to group by source using the max of date, resulting in :

```
ID | source | value | date
---+--------+-------+-----------
2  | 12     | 20    | 2015-11-16
5  | 13     | 50    | 2015-11-16
```

And then the final step would be to sum the values, and then this process is repeated to get the sum value for multiple dates, so this would result in the row

```
 value | date
-------+-----------
 70    | getdate() - 30
```

to use for the rest.

**Where I'm stuck**

I'm trying to group by `source` and use the max of `date` to get the most recent entry for each unique `source`, but if I use the aggregate function or group by, then I can't preserve the `ID` or `value` columns to stick with the chosen max row. It's totally possible I'm just misunderstanding how aggregate functions work.

**Progress so far**

The best place I've gotten to yet is something like

```
with dataInDateRange as (
    select *
    from #historicalData hd
    where hd.date < getdate() - 30
)
select ???, max(date)
from dataInDateRange
group by source
```

But I'm not seeing how I can do this without somehow preserving a unique ID for the row that has the max `date` for each `source` so then I can go back and sum up the numbers.

**Thank you great people for any help/guidance/lessons**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `row_number()`

```
with dataInDateRange as (
    select *
    from #historicalData hd
    where hd.date < getdate() - 30
), rows as (
    select *, 
           row_number() over (partition by source 
                              order by date desc) as rn
    from dataInDateRange
)
SELECT *
FROM rows 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Looks like that works well! I checked by doing `select distinct source from rows` and got the same amount of rows. Nice solution, I'll explain my understanding for myself and any other that might end up here, any corrections would be greatly appreciateed!

The first select gets the data within the desired range, then we do over that data and with a little split for each `source` and order by the `date`, then record the row number within that little grouping to see which one was first, which is then found in `rn`.

Comment: yes, that is correct. just check documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186734.aspx,

Comment: btw, you could merge first two query in a single one. I just make separated for easy to read.